# cpp return different output with same input

Tags: c++

I create a sha256 demo with cpp, and want to repeat it 100000 times.

But I got different output every time with same input. What's wrong in my code?

Sorry I'm newbee to cpp.

Here is my code:

```
void hash_cout(string msg)
{
    vector<unsigned long> block;
    block = convert_to_binary(msg);
    block = pad_to_512bits(block);
    block = resize_block(block);
    string hash = compute_hash(block);
    cout << hash << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    const string message = "abcd";
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) 
    {
        hash_cout(message);
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

Output:

b8863664fd63dc2f92a0858ff7059d4b4c247bd883491c1dffc84380ea320183
1d18c6dd6cd175bee1e6285ffc2ed8d2ca1c582f9818d8ffe4ef539d89e69631
d982784be169c31fe0677ecf5dc03611b9c8602c29eeac3ab71bcc0488f4dabf
888766e7fb731adfefef38ba0287b54e103b61b850a75dd106db16db1c20a25c
054a5efb4e9e67d1ebf9714bf304f78a1df3d3df79d6a793bbf1ac3e90b8af79

I learnt this cpp sha256 code from https://gist.github.com/hak8or/8794351

Comment: Where is the implementation of compute_hash()?

Comment: Your `hash_cout` is declared to return `int` but has no `return` statement. It might not be the cause of this bug, but it causes undefined behaviour and you'd better fix it.

Comment: You are also not returning anything in hash_cout make it void..

Comment: I strongly recommend adding what library you are using to perform the hashing to the question so we have a better frame of reference.

Comment: It would help to have the definitions of every function called in `hash_cout`.

Comment: And at this point consider reducing the loop count to something smaller like 2. If it doesn't work at 2, it won't work at 10 or 10,000.

Comment: There have been at least 2 edits after people commented on your code.  Please post your *real* code, not code you're fixing right now.

Comment: Also without a  loop or anything, just make your string input like "a" or simply call hash_cout("a"); hash_cout("a") and see if that is working, 1 letter might be easier to debug

Comment: I will post all my code, cpp guys reply so quickly..

Comment: I learnt this cpp sha256 example from https://gist.github.com/hak8or/8794351

Comment: If you are trying to implement sha256, check your function against known test values. You can find the correct sha256 value for the null string and "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog" pretty easily with a google search, or by running someone else's good sha256. Be sure to generate it twice, since that's a known issue for you.

Comment: Get a well-tested sha256 function that has been peer-reviewed by thousands of programmers.  The problem with home-made examples of this is simple -- they have not been well tested and may contain bugs, thus debugging such a beast requires *you* to know the intricacies of sha256.  Don't waste time -- get another library if this is the case.

Comment: The implementation you are looking at is probably problematic. I just extracted the main computation part of the original code into a separate function and called it twice with the same input and got two different results in the output.

Comment: @KennyOstrom I will find a new library. Somebody mention the global variables problem...

Comment: Looked at that code. And I'm leery. The writer's not that good with C++. There be some weird stuff in thar. Lot of copying of `vector`s that I don't think is necessary. This odd looking nugget: `input.c_str()[i]`. To be honest, a good compiler  will annihilate this stuff, but... it still sets off the WTF sensor. We probably could debug this, but you're better off looking for a better implementation.

Comment: Read the comments in the code: *SHA-256 is one of the most common one way security hashes used in the wild,SSL, SSH, PGP, and bitcoin all rely on this hash function.* -- So if I'm writing a program where sha256 is a key component, in now way would I grab some unknown or hobby implementation.  Using code like this could get a programmer fired if they made this part of their codebase.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I will use some better sha-256 code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code OP posted on gist.github:

```
string compute_hash(const vector<unsigned long> block)
{

    ...


    unsigned long static H0 = 0x6a09e667;
    unsigned long static H1 = 0xbb67ae85;
    unsigned long static H2 = 0x3c6ef372;
    unsigned long static H3 = 0xa54ff53a;
    unsigned long static H4 = 0x510e527f;
    unsigned long static H5 = 0x9b05688c;
    unsigned long static H6 = 0x1f83d9ab;
    unsigned long static H7 = 0x5be0cd19;

    ...

    H0 = ...

}
```

Variable with static specifier have static storage duration, are allocated when the program starts and deallocated when the program ends, they are initialized only once and preserve their value on each function call. After removing the `static` specifier from these lines, your code no longer produces different results for the same input.

Live version available at [onlinedbg](https://onlinegdb.com/BJpnPVxqm).

Comment: Work perfectly. I remove these static and all get ok.

Comment: @KenNieh -- Is this the only mistake?  You don't know.  I would still get another library, otherwise how would you trust the results, even if the results are now the same?  Equal junk is still junk.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes I will get another library.

Comment: Maybe openssl is a good choice. https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/sha/sha256.c

Answer (score 0):

The library function you are using compute_hash() has static variables H0 to H7. The static variables gets updated every time you call the compute_hash() function.

You will need to create another function that says init_hash() that resets those static variable. The implementation you are using has few issues that needs to be solved.